# curl get response 403

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, http-status-code-403, http-response-codes

### How can I get around the 403 code?

I was trying to get search result from a website, however I got "Response[403]" message, I've found similar get solving 403 error by adding headers to request.get, however it didn't work for my problem. What should I do to correctly get the result I want?

Google Chrome Request

**Request**

```
Request URL: http://178.32.46.165/
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: 178.32.46.165:80
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
```

**Request Headers**

```
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: tr-TR,tr;q=0.9
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Connection: keep-alive
Host: 178.32.46.165
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.102 Safari/537.36
```

Python Request

```
import requests

headers = {
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.102 Safari/537.36',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'Accept-Language': 'tr-TR,tr;q=0.9',
}

response = requests.get('http://178.32.46.165/', headers=headers, verify=False)
print(response)
```

**Response**

```
<Response [403]>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're getting a 403 response, you're likely not meant to be able to access this resource. This is not a Python issue, this is an issue with whatever website you're trying to access.

Additionally, this seems to be a temporary issue. I pasted your code as-is into my Python prompt and received `<Response [200]>`

Comment: It’s possible that OP got themselves blocked for not rotating proxies / user agents - which might be why it worked for you. FYI @YunusK

Answer (score 1):

I think it may provide blocking depending on the country.